# Java: "unknown source" error with unfolding maps package

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

**BACKGROUND**

I'm trying to build a map of earthquake events with data parsed from an RSS feed using the "Unfolding maps" library in Java (this is part of the Coursera course on OOP with Java). In theory, the data from the feed gets parsed into properties of the earthquake (location, magnitude, ...) which then form the basis for these marker objects that get displayed on a map. The libraries that are used are "Processing" and the "Unfolding Maps" library.

**PROBLEM**

Theres an "Unknown Source"  error in the part, where I want to set the color property of the earthquake marker, depending on the magnitude of the event (ie. magnitude > 3 is "yellow").

Here's the **error message**:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.marker.AbstractMarker.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at module3.EarthquakeCityMap.setup(EarthquakeCityMap.java:101)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2365)
at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:873)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:690)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:672)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1383)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1277)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1131)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1394)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And here is the **code**

```
for (Marker marker:markers) {
    if ((int) (marker.getProperty("magnitude")) > 3) {
        System.out.println("trying to set the colour to yellow");
        //marker.setColor(yellow);
        }
    }
```

The line with **"setColor(yellow)"** is commented out, as it seems that this is a problem of its own (may or may not have to do with it).

Anybody have an idea where this may come from and what I could read up on to better understand the problem? I'm pretty new to programming so any advice on how to learn the process of tracing errors / finding out the cause of a problem would be fantastic.

Comment: Your problem not with "Unknown source", your problem with `NullPointerException`. I assume that variable `markers` is null when you try to iterate on it.

Comment: where do you define the color yellow? you can't set colors like this if its not declared anywhere. `marker.setColor(Color.YELLOW);` this should set the color properly.

Comment: `marker` is `null`?

Comment: From the source code, it seems that the `properties` object of `AbstractMarker` has never been set and is null, which gives you a nullpointer when calling `getProperty`. See the code here : https://github.com/tillnagel/unfolding/blob/master/src/de/fhpotsdam/unfolding/marker/AbstractMarker.java . You might have to use one of the constructors with a _properties_ parameter , or call `setProperties` somehow.

Comment: Can you post the code for reading the RSS and creating the markers? Besides your cast to int, which at least with the RSS from the original example shouldn't work (but also not result in an NPE), your code seems fine.
See https://github.com/tillnagel/unfolding/blob/master/examples/de/fhpotsdam/unfolding/examples/data/GeoRSSMarkerApp.java for an example (for Unfolding for P3, but few has changed).

Comment: Hi all, thanks a lot for the help, I hadnt assumed marker would be empty. Looking into the reasons now. Many thanks =)